# How to call function direct from pointer?

Tags: c++

I'm learning how to hook some functions in a gameserver using c++ and I saw a code that call a function directly from a pointer.

Here's the code that I saw :

```
#define DataRecv ((void(*) (BYTE, PBYTE, DWORD, DWORD,…)) 0x004368E0)
```

Here's my code:

```
#define LoadMoveLevel ((void(*) (char *)) 0x0051DF70)
```

How I can call the function LoadMoveLevel?
I tried that :

```
MessageBoxA(NULL, LoadMoveLevel("teste"), "example", MB_OK);
```

but get this error : Argument of type void is imcompatible with parameter type LPCSTR

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get the address `0x0051DF70`? This is not the right way to do this.

Comment: You need to provide more info about `LoadMoveLevel`. If I google it then the only results are a *member function* which returns `int` .

Comment: Its a function with address 0x0051DF70 inside the gameserver

Comment: @Bruno Yes, but how did *you* learn that address? Usually such addresses are not stable. They are not suitable for use in source code. Instead, the server should define an interface which you can use.

Comment: @Bruno but what is its return type, parameters, calling convention? Is it the same member function I mentioned? (if so then you are going to need to take extra measures). There's more to a function than its address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) the `MessageBoxA` function has the following signature:

> int WINAPI MessageBox(
>    _In_opt_ HWND    hWnd,
>    _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpText,
>    _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpCaption,
>    *In*     UINT    uType
>   );

You can see that the 2nd argument is of type `LPCTSTR` but you're function returns `void`. Therefore, you cannot call it in the 2nd parameter because it does not return the required type.

`#define LoadMoveLevel ((void(*) (char *)) 0x0051DF70)`
`//                      ^^^^ // This is the return type of the function`

**Note:** The 'A' appended to the message box function name means you're using the ANSI version (as opposed the the UNICODE version) and the 2nd argument is actually `LPCSTR` (i.e., `const char*`) in your case.

As [R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434551/r-sahu) mentions to call it as a parameter the the message box function the return type would need to be changed from `void` to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 1):

According to definition of `MessageBoxA`,

> int WINAPI MessageBox(
>         _In_opt_ HWND    hWnd,
>         _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpText,
>         _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpCaption,
>         _In_     UINT    uType);

When you call `MessageBoxA(NULL, LoadMoveLevel("teste"), "example", MB_OK);`, the 2nd parameter needs a `LPCTSTR`, but you return `void` by

`#define LoadMoveLevel ((void(*) (char *)) 0x0051DF70)`

Answer (score 1):

First load the interface: `#include "MoveCommand.h"`

Then call the function by its proper name: `gMoveCommand.LoadMoveLevel("teste");`

The return value is still an `int`, not a `char*`. Please refer to the server documentation to learn about proper usage.

(Seeing something like `#define DataRecv` would cause me to run away from a project. Do not take any of this muOnline clone as an example of good, or even valid, C++.)

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `MessageBoxA` is of type `LPCSTR`. The way you have defined `LoadMoveLevel`, the return value of `LoadMoveLevel("teste")` is `void`. That's what the compiler is complaining about.

If the function that lives at the address `0x0051DF70` is supposed to return `void` indeed, you cannot use `LoadMoveLevel`. If that function is supposed to return a `LPCSTR`, then, you have to change `LoadMoveLevel` to:

```
#define LoadMoveLevel ((LPCSTR (*) (char *)) 0x0051DF70)
```

and then, the call

```
MessageBoxA(NULL, LoadMoveLevel("teste"), "example", MB_OK);
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined LoadMoveLevel() to be a call via a pointer to a function that returns `void`.   The second argument of `MessageBoxA()` is a (`const`) `char *`.   A return of `void` from a function does not yield any value, so cannot be converted to anything.   Hence the error.

What the macro is doing is converting the value to a pointer (to function) and then calling the function.   To make it compile, change your macro to either

```
#define LoadMoveLevel ((LPCSTR (*) (char *)) 0x0051DF70)
```

or (expanding `LPCSTR`) to

```
#define LoadMoveLevel (((char *) (*) (char *)) 0x0051DF70)
```

Note that what you are doing is extremely dangerous.   Converting an arbitrary value to a function pointer in order to call it relies on there ACTUALLY being valid code at that location.    Odds are, if you do not understand the syntax (as per your question) you do not know how to ensure that the code at that location corresponds to a function that accepts a `char *` as an argument, and returns a `char *`.

Comment: Sorry, the function return an int value.
I fixed it to #define LoadMoveLevel ((int(*) (char *)) 0x0051DF70)
But when I try to call it like :LoadMoveLevel("teste") it crash.

Comment: The crashing is an example of what I was hinting at in my comment about what you're doing being dangerous.   `MessageBoxA()` expects a `char *` for the second argument.   There aren't many circumstances in which an `int` value (returned by your function) can be safely passed to `MessageBoxA()` (which will use that `int` as if it was a pointer).   More work (e.g. writing the `int` to a string, and passing the string) is probably needed.   But that is going well beyond the question you asked, so I won't run down that line of discussion further.